# Can vector fields in manifolds with corner and sharp edges still satisfy Poincare-Hopf theorem?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds

We know that the sum of singularity index of the vector fields on a sphere equal to Euler characteristics of sphere, satisfying the Poincare-Hopf theorem. But how about situations of the geometry with edges and corners?

And if you can provide related references, I will be more appreciated.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/415487/83537

Comment: But I need some reference. Like journals or books.

Comment: The quoted question has a reference (inside the quotation): Guillemin and Pollack. Have you checked that source already?

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks very much for remindering.